# How to convert date to UTC midnight using PHP

Tags: php

i tried to pass date to hubspot.But it shows following error message
[message] => 1462127400 is at 22:8:47.400 UTC, not midnight!

how to convert date to UTC midnight format using PHP

Comment: Do you want to convert a unix timestamp to the unix timestamp of midnight on that day? Is the timestamp going to be in seconds or miliseconds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short way to get start (midnight) of UTC **current day:**

```
echo date_create( date('Y-m-d'), timezone_open( 'UTC' ) )->getTimestamp();
```

will output (Now it's 2016-04-02 10:22 UTC):

```
1459555200
```

Check:

```
$date = date_create( date('Y-m-d'), timezone_open( 'UTC' ) );
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;
echo $date->getTimestamp() . PHP_EOL;
```

output:

```
2016-04-02 00:00:00
1459555200
```

To obtain start of UTC day according to given **date string** (i.e. default TimeZone TOT):

```
$dateString = '2016-03-15 23:05:00';

$date = new DateTime( $dateString );
#       └──────────┴┈┈┈┈> is the same as date_create()
$date->setTimezone( timezone_open( 'UTC' ) );
$date->modify( 'midnight' );
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;
echo $date->getTimestamp() . PHP_EOL;
```

output:

```
2016-03-15 00:00:00
1458000000
```

One-line way:

```
echo date_create($dateString)->setTimezone(timezone_open('UTC'))->modify('midnight')->getTimestamp();
```

To obtain start of UTC day according to given **timestamp:**

```
$timeStamp  = 1458036300;

$date = new DateTime( "@$timeStamp" );
#                      ↑ use @ to create a DateTime from timestamp
$date->modify( 'midnight' );
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;
echo $date->getTimestamp() . PHP_EOL;
```

output:

```
2016-03-15 00:00:00
1458000000
```

One-line way:

```
echo date_create("@$timeStamp")->modify('midnight')->getTimestamp();
```

Note that with UNIX timestamp we don't need to set TimeZone, because UNIX timestamp is UTC-based.